# K&R C Programming Language - Reverse Polish Calculator

Tags: c, kernighan-and-ritchie

I'm relatively new to C (but decently well versed in programming in general) and I've been trying to self study via the K&R C book. I've found myself stumped when trying to understand how the example Reverse Polish Calculator works. Below I have provided the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define MAXOP 100
#define NUMBER '0'
#define MAXVAL 100
#define BUFSIZE 100

int getop(char []);
void push(double);
double pop(void);
int getch(void);
void ungetch(int);

int main(void) {
    int type;
    double op2;
    char s[MAXOP];

    while ((type = getop(s)) != EOF) {
        switch (type) {
        case NUMBER:
            push(atof(s));
            break;
        case '+':
            push(pop() + pop());
            break;
        case '*':
            push(pop() * pop());
            break;
        case '-':
            op2 = pop();
            push(pop() - op2);
            break;
        case '/':
            op2 = pop();
            if (op2 != 0.0)
                push(pop() / op2);
            else
                printf("error: zero divisor\n");
            break;
        case '\n':
            printf("\t%.8g\n", pop());
            break;
        default:
            printf("error: unknown command %s\n", s);
            break;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

int sp = 0;
double val[MAXVAL];

void push(double f) {
    if (sp < MAXVAL)
        val[sp++] = f;
    else
        printf("error: stack full, can't push %g\n", f);
}

double pop(void) {
    if (sp > 0)
        return val[--sp];
    else {
        printf("error: stack empty\n");
        return 0.0;
    }
}

int getop(char s[]) {
    int i, c;

    while ((s[0] = c  = getch()) == ' ' || c == '\t')
        ;
    s[1] = '\0';

    if (!isdigit(c) && c != '.')
        return c;

    i = 0;
    if (isdigit(c))
        while (isdigit(s[++i] = c = getch()))
            ;
    if (c == '.')
        while (isdigit(s[++i] = c = getch()))
            ;
    s[i] = '\0';
    if (c != EOF)
        ungetch(c);
    return NUMBER;
}

char buf[BUFSIZE];
int bufp = 0;

int getch(void) {
    return (bufp > 0) ? buf[--bufp] : getchar();
}

void ungetch(int c) {
    if (bufp >= BUFSIZE)
        printf("ungetch: too many characters\n");
    else
        buf[bufp++] = c;
}
```

With this I have several questions:

1. Why the line `s[1] = '\0'?` There aren't any statements in the while loop checking for blanks, so wouldn't an input of   `1 2 - 4 5 + *` just result in  `\0 2 - 4 5 + *`?
2. Every time we check `type = getop(s)`, how does the program know to get the next operator or operand? If I remember correctly, having a null character in the middle of a character means every character after the null character is ignored. With the `i = 0`, aren't we always starting at the beginning of the input string?
3. For the - and / operators, why must we set `op2 = pop()`? I understand that these are not commutative operators, but shouldn't `pop() - pop()` or `pop() / pop()` be enough to describe the order of operands?

Comment: #3 `op2 = pop()`... Think it through. Fetch the **second** operand (top of stack), then you can fetch the **first** operand (the new top of stack)... Think it through and it's somewhat obvious. :-)

Comment: _"I'm relatively new to C"_ - Then the best advice I can give is to chew smaller portions. Make **one** function that does **exactly** what you want it to do and don't continue until you are sure it actually does. Next step is using that function in another function, that you also scrutinize the same way. It'll help you identify problems.

Comment: Clearly you're studying the 2nd edition of K&R, but even that one is *way* out of date, anticipating as it does the first version of the international standard (C90, now > 30 years old).  Do yourself a favor and choose a more recent book that teaches a more recent version of C.

Comment: #1 Look carefully and see that leading whitespace is ignored. Look carefully at where `s[]` is being populated by `getch()`... There's no "clobbering" somewhere in the middle of an entire line of entry. Each term (and operand) is dealt with in sequence...

Comment: In addition to K&R being completely outdated, the code examples are also known to contain a lot of obscure and subtle things. Even C veterans will have to be on their toes when reading goo like this - so for beginners it's pretty much mission impossible to understand everything going on the code. Particularly when looking at completely obfuscated lines like `while ((s[0] = c  = getch()) == ' ' || c == '\t')`. I don't know what drives a person to write a line like that, but a genuine will to teach someone else C is surely not the reason.

Answer (score 4):

1. Notice that the `while` loop assigns `s[0]` each time through the loop. So `s` will just be a 1-character string. The null terminator is put in the second byte, which is `s[1]`. The loop is creating a string containing the next non-whitespace character. The code after that will extend the string for longer tokens, and uses `s[i] = '\0';` after the loops to add the proper null terminator there. It might have been clearer to put `s[1] = '\0'` in the `if (!isdigit(c) && c != '.')` block, since that's the only case where we return before the later loops.
2. `getop()` uses `getch()` to get characters from standard input. It's not processing the same string that was returned previously, it's overwriting it.
3. C doesn't specify the order of function calls in most expression. So if you write `pop() - pop()`, there's no way of telling whether the top of the stack will be the first or second operand. For commutative operators this doesn't matter, but for subtraction and division you need to do the pops in separate statements to ensure that you get them in the proper order. Otherwise, `3 2 -` could result in either `1` or `-1`.